# Bookmarks advanced search

Tags: search, bookmarks

My use-case: I want to search my bookmarks to find everything about Git. When I search "Git" — I get every link from github.com as well, and I can't exclude it from search. Even if I could limit search to i.e. page title, there still would be non-relevant results, like those from github.com containing "- GitHub" in a title. So there is clearly the need of advanced search queries with filtering and etc.

But it is surprisingly difficult to find something that will allow to do that. My bookmarks are in Chrome but any sane tool would fit. I didn't find any extension in Chrome or Firefox add-on stores which works like that. I also not found any OS utilities. There are some fancy "bookmark managers" out there which are a complete overkill and a pain to setup and I don't know if they will even do the trick.

Are there any sane options to do advanced bookmark search?

Comment: There are a few history manager extensions in the chrome web store. I found [History Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-manager/ifekbbngjjcachfekcpeejphmkeckged) to be useful for me and well rated.

_**Caveat Emptor**:_ read the reviews carefully. Some had complaints of deleting data or other destructive things.

Comment: I think it might be better to just write something myself. First, use some parser to extract raw bookmarks data, then use some programming language to search this data. Never expected it to be such an "underdeveloped" field though, I guess nobody using bookmarks anymore

Comment: I'd be interested in checking that out if you choose to make it publically available. Thx

Comment: @SaxDaddy check this out: https://superuser.com/questions/1371108/bookmarks-advanced-search/1382125#1382125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple JavaScript [snippet](https://gist.github.com/andreyvolokitin/76de55c5fc8f281ac528b4cf305cc8f0) which can be used to search exported bookmarks HTML in the browser via browser developer tools console. In order to use it:

1. export your bookmarks into HTML file
2. open this file in the browser
3. open browser developer tools console
4. paste the [snippet code](https://gist.github.com/andreyvolokitin/76de55c5fc8f281ac528b4cf305cc8f0) into the console
5. replace `query` variable with your search query and hit enter

Results will be showed in the browser window. Refresh the page and repeat to make a new search